# Batch Script to delete only files with .zip extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I want to skip the latest `3 files created` and `delete the rest of the files`. What I need is that if there is text, xml and zip files we need to delete only the zip files and leave the text and xml files behind and the total files left should be 3.If there are 3 or more files other than .zip files, delete all .zip files; if there are less, keep the newest .zip files so that there are 3 files left in total. Can anyone help. I am stuck with this

For example(inside bracket created date of files):
 `Folder A contains - aa.txt(2/1/18), bb.xml(3/1/18), cc.zip(4/1/18), dd.zip(2/1/18),ee.zip(5/1/18)`

What I need after deleting  is
`aa.txt,  bb.xml, ee.zip`

This is what I have written

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=C:\source"
SET /a retain=3

FOR /f "skip=%retain%delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d /o-d "%targetdir%\*.zip" '
 ) DO DEL (DEL "%targetdir%\%%a.zip"

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: What if there are more than 3 files with an extension other than `.zip`?

Comment: Need to keep all that  files@aschipfl

Comment: So basically, if there are 3 or more files other than `.zip` files, delete all `.zip` files; if there are less, keep the newest `.zip` files so that there are 3 files left in total. That is what you want exactly, is that correct? Please [edit] your question accordingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the parameters of your question, a very simple method, *although not the most efficient or speedy*, would be to do this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "targetdir=C:\source"
Set "retain=3"
CD /D "%targetdir%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
For /F "Skip=%retain% Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D/O-D/TC'
) Do If /I "%%~xA"==".zip" Del "%%A"
```

Comment: I am not getting the solution with this sir@Compo

Comment: @Reenu, you need to try to better explain what you need then. My understanding, and this code, deletes all `.zip` files in `%targerdir%`, except for any which are  listed in the `3` most recently `created` files in that directory.

Comment: I have tried this sir. I am not able to delete even the zip files@Compo

Comment: @Reenu, I have made a modification to the code without changing the intent.

Comment: `Not able to delete` does not adequately help me or anyone else to debug or modify the code accordingly. Please provide a better explanation of what is happening or not happening by removing the first line of my script and running it by typing in its full path at the command prompt.

Comment: I am not able to perform any action. All the 9 files remains as it is@Compo

Comment: I used the `Echo` command deliberately so that you could see what would be deleted, without doing so. I have now removed it; try it now!

Comment: Thankyou so much@Compo